# Elmah, what is the most efficient persistent mechanism for errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, elmah

I have an asp.net MVC application in Azure web apps which connects to SQL Azure.

Currently I store Elmah errors in App_data. These can build up. Also I feel writing these files is inefficient. In addition when you download the "Next 50" errors, there can be a hit on the server.

How can I improve my persistence strategy? I suspect it may be to use a database. Would this be a seperate database to the application database or the same one?

I am also testing Application Insights. At present I suspect that Elmah has a role alongside Application Insights, but I might be wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer you can store the log files in a sql azure database . or you can go with a cheaper option of azure table storage which is a no-sql based data store. There is a provider available for the same. 
https://github.com/MisinformedDNA/Elmah.AzureTableStorage
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ELMAH.Tables/
or if you looking more at a data dump of your logs say in xml format and does not really need a queryable format you can opt for a much cheaper azure blob storage .
https://github.com/dampee/Blob-Elmah

Comment: Azure DB works well. Now implemented. Also we found that one DB can serve multiple applications. Also we were concerned that more Elmah DB would demand more Azure cost, but it seems to run happily off Basic.

Comment: yes it totally depends on the business use case. if you log a lot and not really look up logs that much then it does not require a relational database. you should look at table storage and blobs. In some cases people log a lot for analytical purpose and use a system like splunk to run through logs..

Answer (score 1):

An Elmah database can be used in a separate Azure DB to not consume your "Business" database DTUs and by the way never affect it's performance if you want to log a lot of things.

On the one hand Elmah can take care of "Functionnal" logs, on the other and application Insight can do telemery and monitoring logs, besides you can enable server and applications logs in the Azure Portal to get automatic logs in a storage account, [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/) is an overview of those server and application logs.